# Login Fails For One Account, But Not For Others

Tags: drupal, issues, user-account

A user on our client's CiviCRM site [CiviCRM(4.6.5)/Drupal(7.36)] is having trouble with her login. Each time she attempts to login, she is greeted with an error indicating that she has entered her password incorrectly.
Testing her login from another location/network, I am able to login using her credentials.
Using a JoinMe session to share her screen, I am able to login to CiviCRM using my credentials (as well as several others), but when I use hers, her login fails.
I have cleared the cache on her browser, cleared caches on CiviCRM, and have tried updating her user-password, but get the same results each time I attempt to login from her PC (Windows10).
It seems that there is something wrong with her account, but I have directly inspected her user-record in the Drupal users table and can find no anomalies which would explain why she cannot login. Her user-roles are all correct as well, but still she cannot login.
Has anyone else had this problem with one of their CiviCRM users?

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, this appears to be a Drupal issue, not a CiviCRM issue as Civi is not involved in checking passwords. I'm just fishing here, but I would try the following:

- Clear the Drupal caches.
- Delete relevant cookies in the browser.
- See if you can login using a different browser on the same machine.
- Change the users password.